# Unable to find a specification for `ARCore (~> 1.2.1)

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods, arcore

I'm trying to compile and build the ARCore example provided here :

https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-ios-sdk

My Podfile looks as follows

```
`=> cat Podfile 
target 'MyTarget'
platform :ios, '11.0'
pod 'ARCore', '~> 1.2.1'
pod 'Firebase/Core', '~> 4.11'
pod 'Firebase/Database', '~> 4.11'`
```

When I run pod install, I get the folllowing error :

`==> pod install
Analyzing dependencies
[!] Unable to find a specification for`ARCore (~> 1.2.1)``

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run `pod update` or `pod install --repo-update`.

Your podspec repo is probably does not include 1.2.1 yet.